# Accessing generic sender's properties in a single event (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have made a Tree View containing different color names. Each color has it's respective foreground (e.g. The tree item view having Header="Red" has Foreground="Red" too)

Now, I want to change the background color of the window according to the item the user double clicks on. For example, if User clicks on "Red", the window background turns Red.
Also, I just want to make a single command/ event to do that, so it can be used by all the tree view items' MouseDoubleClick property.

Is there a way to access the item's foreground in code-behind?
I'm trying the following but it's not working:

```
public void ColorChanger(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{   
    this.Background= sender as TreeViewItem.Foreground; 
}
```

Comment: `(sender as TreeViewItem).Foreground`?

Comment: Better `((TreeViewItem)sender).Foreground`. In case sender is not a TreeViewItem, it would correctly throw in InvalidCastException instead of an incorrect NullReferenceException. Only use the `as` operator if you also check its result for `null`.

Comment: Hint: don't ever rename event handlers, rather make a new method and call it from standard named event handler. *"I just want to make a single command"* - that's very good idea considering tag [tag:wpf].

Comment: @stuartd it worked, Thanks!! I wonder why you chose to comment rather answering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work provided that `sender` is a `TreeViewItem`:

```
public void ColorChanger(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TreeViewItem menuItem)
        this.Background = menuItem.Foreground;
}
```